# Is a good idea to add references to a C# repository?

Tags: c#, repository, nuget, libraries

I have a project that uses several libraries, is it possible to add those libraries (that i've imported with NuGet) to the Git repository, and if so is it a good idea to do such thing?

Sorry if the question is off-topic or not relevant, but I'm kinda newbie on git and version control

Comment: You don't have to because every time you build the solution with missing libraries, nuget automatically downloads them for you. It also helps to keep you repository less in size in Git.

Comment: Thanks! didn't know that... when I clone the branch on a different computer, all of the libraries appears as missing, that's why I asked... didn't realised that I have to re-build the solution